# Keyboard volume pedals

Tags: keyboard, performing, keyboard-pedals

I have a Yamaha S90 XS synth and when I perform I would like to control the volume of one or more of the zone sliders (in Performance mode) with foot pedals so I can quickly switch from backup to lead.

In case that isn't clear enough, here is an example. Say piano in zone 1 is at volume 115, strings in zone 2 are at volume 50, and the pads in zone 3 and 4 are typically at 0 (this one isn't used much live) and 10 respectively. That would be something like the volumes when I am playing backup. However, the strings (zone 2) become way to live for lead in that, so I would want to back that down to about 20. Also, there may be different times when I want zone 3 or 4 at much higher volumes.

Are there pedal board setups that allow this, and if there are, what would the S90 XS support?

I have two foot pedal control inputs (1/4" size input), a sustain pedal input (in use obviously), and an assignable foot pedal control.

Comment: Did you figure it out? I have the same question

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't figured out a good system yet, and at this point, I just adjust the sliders with my hands. I purchased the FC7 (well built, nice pedal), which I use for overall volume control. I haven't figured out how to use it for just one of the zones. Let me know if you get some good vibes going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know this keyboard so I am not sure but this might help : http://faq.yamaha.com/us/en/article/index/id/6812/?search_query=s90xs%20fc7&current_page_id=1

Comment: Actually, thank you very much for resurrecting this post and pointing that out to me. While the link you posted wasn't exactly what I was looking for, it did lead to exactly what I was looking for (hence the link edit in case it helps future visitors)! I hadn't known about that FAQ, and was very excited to have this question answered. Thank you!

Comment: I wanted to thank you again for this answer. It has actually opened up a whole world on my keyboard I never knew existed. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, I am glad it helped you... Keyboards are complex and I am sure most people (including me) only use 25% of their ability.